# sikuli-Python(Want to fetch a single Record)

Tags: sikuli-script

how to select the record in application screen using sikuli-Python.

(This is my screen in application).
i don't have search option in my screen. now i want to fetch a single record from the screen. Somebody Please Help me. I am new to sikuli-python

Comment: is there anybody to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to extract data:

1. Using built in OCR which is largely unreliable and will work in only certain cases. Worth a try however if nothing else working.
2. Get the data via simulated keyboard and mouse actions. For example, if you can manually navigate to the field using keyboard and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy data to clipboard, you can do the same with Sikuli.